# WheelNav not working on CodePen but is in Code Snippet

Tags: javascript, css, raphael, wheelnav.js

The following code runs somewhat inside the following snippet.  It does cut off the bottom half.  But it **doesn't work at all** on [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmoKvG) or my private server.  It generates 1000+ errors on CodePen.  Why could this be?  I am very confused as to what I am missing.

```js
wheel = new wheelnav('wheelDiv');
wheel.clockwise = false;
wheel.createWheel(['title-0', 'title-1', 'title-2', 'title-3', 'title-4']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/wheelnav/1.7.0/wheelnav.min.js"></script>


<div id="wheelDiv"></div>
```

What I'm running on my home server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/wheelnav/1.7.0/wheelnav.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wheelDiv"></div>
  <script>
  wheel = new wheelnav('wheelDiv');
  wheel.clockwise = false;
  wheel.createWheel(['title-0', 'title-1', 'title-2', 'title-3', 'title-4']);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wheelnav.js](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/) library currently works with modified raphael.js.
Your current issue fixed [here](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/commit/fea62ef53f3a44986d765e6dd1edd089900f2565).

You can use modified raphael.js from here: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wheelnav@1.7.1/js/dist/raphael.min.js

Here is my working template on CodePen: https://codepen.io/softwaretailoring/pen/OWYBjy

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wheelnav@1.7.1/js/dist/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wheelnav@1.7.1/js/dist/wheelnav.min.js"></script>
```